# Monitor serial number is not returned vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am using the vb.net code bellow to try to get the monitor serial number of any computer on the network. The code works well for a local computer but I got 0 as result for remote computers. However, with the same logic of the code, I can get other values on remote computers like the ManufacturerName by instead. I ran a WMI Code Creator and I also got 0 as result for a remote computer. Using a vbscript I could get the right serial number, so I know the result from the vb code is wrong. I would appreciate any help.

```
 Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim objWMIService, colItems As Object
    Dim strComputer As String, serialNum As String, instanceName As String
    strComputer = "TDS57771-CCU"

    objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\wmi")

    colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM WMIMonitorID")

    For Each objItems In colItems
        serialNum = ""
        If objItems.SerialNumberID Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox("XXX")
        Else
            'arrSerialNumberID = objItems.SerialNumberID()
            For Each arrValue As UInt16 In objItems.SerialNumberID
                serialNum = serialNum & Chr(arrValue)

            Next

        End If
        MsgBox(serialNum)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the end I could not find a way to use the WMIMonitorId class to get the serial number of a remote computer from a .NET App. However, I needed that value. So, I got a very good vbs script from https://www.itsupportguides.com/vbs-scripts/vbs-script-get-monitor-serial-number-remotely/. I have to say that the author did a very good job. So, I am calling that script from my visuaL basic app, sending as argument the computer name and then wait for the vbscript to finish. I also changed the sript to allow it to update my access database. In that way, everytime a new computer is entered to the data base from my App, I could also get its monitor information.